# Dynamically created element not appearing when page is printed

Tags: jquery, html, printing

I've some dynamically created elements with jQuery:

```
<body>
<a href="#" id="trigger">test</a>
    <a href="javascript:window.print()">print</a>
</body>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trigger').click(function(e) {
        $('body').append('<div id="test"></div>');
    });
});
```

The CSS:

```
#test { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50px; 
    top: 100px; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 25px; 
    background-color: #F00; 
}
```

As you can see I've created a `print` button and would like to print out that `#test` element. Unfortunately the sheet only has the two buttons. It seems that you can't print out dynamic elements.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"It seems that you can't print out dynamic elements."* Yes, you can. The problem lies elsewhere, perhaps with your print stylesheet?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with print stylesheet?

Comment: Try adding the `window.print()` inside the `$('#trigger').click()` function, after you append the div.

Comment: @supersize: If you don't know, you don't have one. :-) You can apply different CSS to the page when it's being viewed in the browser and when it's printed. ***Very*** useful.

Comment: And maybe the problem is that there's nothing inside your div. Try adding some text and then printing it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed very useful. I didn't ask it but its another problem I had. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

When you print a web page, the browser automatically ignores background color (because you usually don't want to spend your entire color cartridge to print a web page background). Your generated div is empty and the only way it is visible on the page is because of its different background color.

If you add content to the div or e.g. a border it should be visible in the printout as well.

Comment: Oh, it was just there *waiting* for someone to see it. :-)

Comment: okay that was right! tried with border and worked. but is it possible to print the background-color with a workaround?